NextJS : Implement parallel routing with Next.js 14 for tab navigation without re-rendering pages?
I'm working on a project using Next.js 14 and I'm trying to implement a tab navigation system where each tab corresponds to a different route (/resume and /source). The goal is to navigate between these tabs without re-rendering the pages each time the route changes.
In these pages, I'm using the react-pdf library (https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf) to display a PDF document. I want the PDF document to remain displayed without reloading when I navigate between the tabs. However, I still want the navigation URL to change to reflect the active tab.
Here's a simplified version of my current setup:
// packages/client/src/app/editor/[uuid]/@content/source/page.tsx
import React from 'react';
import SourceDocument from '@/app/editor/[uuid]/@content/source/components/source-document';

export default async function SourcePage({ params: { uuid } }: SourcePageProps): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  // ...fetching data...
  return <SourceDocument url={resumeSourceFile.url} />;
}

// packages/client/src/app/editor/[uuid]/@content/source/components/source-document.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { DocumentViewer } from '@/components/document-viewer';

const SourceDocument = ({ url }: SourceDocumentProps): JSX.Element => {
  // ...state and handlers...
  return <DocumentViewer onLoadSuccess={onLoadSuccess} numPages={numPages} file={url} />;
};

export default React.memo(SourceDocument);

I've tried using React.memo to prevent unnecessary re-renders, but it doesn't seem to work in this case because the components are unmounted and remounted when the route changes.
I want to achieve the following:

When I navigate from /resume to /source (or vice versa), if I have visited the page before, it should not re-render but serve exactly the same content.
The navigation URL should change to reflect the active tab.
If I hard reload the page, then it should re-render.

Any suggestions on how to implement this in Next.js 14 would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

You could use a hash route to represent the client state inside the client's browser. It will satisfy all 3 of your requirements. Also keep in mind that the server won't have an idea about the hash. Check out this answer to get the idea. Or alternatively use route queries like in this nextjs specific article

you should be able to use a layout where the tab navigation sits and then use different pages inside the layout folder structure to represent the content.

what you're trying to achieve is a Persistent Layout. Both your resume and source components have to share the same parent-layout file if you want to avoid them re-rendering when you navigate between the two tabs as parallel routes.
To create parallel routes, you’ll need to define them as slots using the @folder convention. So you'd have @resume and @source within documents for example. The folder structure should look like so:


├── app
│   ├── (custom-route-group)
│   │   ├── documents
│   │   │   ├── @resume
│   │   │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │   │   ├── @source
│   │   │   │   └── page.tsx
│   │   │   ├── layout.tsx
│   │   │   └── page.tsx



// The parent layout file houses both the resume and source components (also called slots in this case). The slots are then automatically passed to the layout in the same route segment as its props.

export default function DocumentLayout({ children, resume, source }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <main>
      <div>{ children }</div>
      <div>{ resume }</div>
      <div>{ source }</div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

Having a route group (e.g. (custom-route-group)) is not a must. It is optional and it just help to organise your app folder.
I would assume you're using the App Router in Next.js. This solution would be slightly different in the Pages router.
Let me know if you have any questions.

Thank you for you response. I explored this solution when I read the nextjs docs, the problem is that if i do this, I cannot bind each tab (source and resume) to a route segment. My wish is to be able to navigate to /resume and /source, without having to reload the page. But I think this is not possible

In the world of tech, nothing is impossible really. I hope you find a solution that works for you. Do share your findings with the rest of us if you get it to work eventually.

Using Tailwind for styling.
In the layout.tsx
export default function Layout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-2">
      <TabNavigationPanel
        tabs={[<text>Categories</text>, <text>Courses</text>]}
        hrefs={['/dashboard/courses/category', '/dashboard/courses/course']}
      />
      <div className="mt-5 flex h-full w-full flex-col rounded-lg border-2 border-black p-4">
        {children}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

hrefs are different pages defined in separate page.tsx files.
Definition of TabNavigationPanel
'use client';

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Tab, TabList, TabPanel, Tabs } from 'react-tabs';

import Link from 'next/link';
import clsx from 'clsx';

interface CustomTabContainerProps {
  tabs: React.ReactNode[];
  hrefs: String[];
}

const TabNavigationPanel = ({
  tabs,
  hrefs,
}: CustomTabContainerProps): JSX.Element => {
  const [selectedTab, onSelect] = useState(0);
  return (
    <Tabs className="h-full">
      <TabList className="flex flex-row rounded-lg bg-black">
        {tabs.map((item, index) => (
          <Link key={`${item}${index}`} href={`${hrefs[index] ?? ''}`}>
            <Tab
              className={clsx('p-4', {
                'text-white': index !== selectedTab,
                'font-bold text-amber-400': index === selectedTab,
              })}
              onClick={() => onSelect(index)}
            >
              {item}
            </Tab>
          </Link>
        ))}
      </TabList>
    </Tabs>
  );
};

export default TabNavigationPanel;


I ran into this recently as well and figured out a solution with Parallel Routes. Similar to how Layouts are persistent, this approach also allows for routes to be persistent as you require.
Here's how. For your use case, you will want a file tree as this:
app
├── @resume
│   ├── default.tsx
│   └── resume
│       ├── @sub_a
│       │   ├── default.tsx
│       │   └── sub-a
│       │       └── page.tsx
│       ├── layout.jsx
│       ├── not-found.tsx
│       └── page.tsx
├── @source
│   ├── default.tsx
│   └── source
│       ├── layout.jsx
│       └── page.tsx

And then in your layout file, you can conditionally render either the slot for resume or source or children based on the currently active pathname.
The trick here is to use display: none so that we don't tear down the tab component completely, and hence maintain its state.
Here's a helper <Route /> component which you can use to handle the conditional showing of each tab/page.
// Route.tsx

"use client";
import { usePathname } from "next/navigation";

type Route = {
  path: string;
  component: React.ReactNode;
};

export function Route({ path, component, exact }: Route) {
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const isActive = path === pathname

  return (
    <div key={path} style={{ display: isActive ? "block" : "none" }}>
      {component}
    </div>
  );
}

And then an example Layout file itself:
// layout.tsx

import "./globals.css";
import { Route } from "./Route";

export default function Layout({
  children,
  resume,
  source,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
  resume: React.ReactNode;
  source: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Route path="/" component={children} />
      <Route path="/resume" component={resume} />
      <Route path="/source" component={source} />
    </div>
  );
}


The approach is not foolproof and there are some rough edges/gotchas.
There's a repo here with an example and known issues with the approach here. Hope this helps you and others!
